# Nuxt js(2.15.7 ) i18n when add vue plugin loader (app.i18n.__onNavigate is not a function)

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
{
  mode: "universal",
  // target: 'static',
  ssr: true,
  router:{
    mode: 'hash',
    middleware: ['i18n']
  },
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/i18n.js'
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Btw, `mode` is obsolete. You should use `target: static` or `target: server` as of today. It will still be isomorphic if you do have `ssr:  true`. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode

Answer (score 0):

you have probably not installed `nuxt/i18n` properly: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/setup

Start with `yarn add nuxt-i18n` then, add it to the modules

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
{
  modules: [
    'nuxt-i18n',
  ],
}
```

---

A plugin is not really required here, and it will be easier to use a Nuxt module that is meant for this purpose.
Also, we cannot see the content of your plugins nor the rest of the code, hence my recommendation here.